# PRISM - Create a new dialog instance to each interaction request -

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I´m facing a problem:

If I do the first request to the dialog and add it to Grid.Children...some times I have to call another dialog in this activated one, and in this case the same instance is being passed throw the action, and the application tries to add the same instance to the GRID children again....And I get an exception.

To each request I do in view model I´d like to create a new instance of "views:DialogControl", how can I acomplish this?

Follow my view interaction :

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding Path=NotificationToDialog}">
            <views:MessageAction>
                <views:MessageAction.Dialog>
                    <views:DialogControl />
                </views:MessageAction.Dialog>
            </views:MessageAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a factory for creating dialogs, instead of an instance to the dialog itself. I.e. you implement a `MessageAction.DialogFactory` property, in place of `MessageAction.Dialog`.
Then in your (modified) `MessageAction`, you can create a fresh dialog from the factory when it is triggered.

However, you will likely run into additional problems if you are simply cramming the new dialog into the parent Grid (e.g. disabling the other dialog, etc.). It may be better to queue the interaction requests in the action.

Answer (score 0):

What `Type` is `MessageAction.Dialog` of? You could avoid your problem if you create a `ContentControl` for each show dialog request as your dialog element and then instead of passing the concrete instance of `DialogControl` model it to be a `ContentTemplate` for your just created `ContentControl`.

This will keep your Action generic and a new instance is created for every request. The `Type` of `MessageAction.DialogTemplate` could be `DataTemplate` for example.